# What version of Drupal am I running?

Tags: migrations

I have a really old site that has been neglected for almost 20 years, it runs Drupal, only problem is that I cannot figure out which version of Drupal I am running.

Index.php has this:

// $Id: index.php,v 1.90.2.1 2006/12/12 13:50:59 killes Exp $

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you should also consider that a Drupal 4.7 site that hasn't been touched is likely compromised, either the site itself from unapplied patches or issued addressed in later versions, or the server itself since the Apache 1.x  / PHP 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

That's a version somewhere between [4.7.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.5) and  [4.7.11](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.11).

You mentioned in a deleted comment that you were hoping to upgrade one version at a time, presumably to a much more recent version; to be honest, I'm not sure there's much hope of upgrading a site that old.

I don't think there was an official migration path from 4.x to 5.x, maybe not even a proper one for 5.x to 6.x. 6.x to 7.x had a path, but was a pretty challenging process if memory serves. Same again for 7.x to 8.x.

It might be worth considering whether a rebuild, or a custom migration straight out of the old database into Drupal 10, is a better option.

Comment: Thank you! Then I guess I will be trying to extract the data directly from the DB. Seems an interesting challenge.

Comment: Thinking it through a bit more, I don't think it'll be too difficult - the shape of the data back then was a lot more simple. Migrating HTML into a suitable text format, and transferring files, might be the trickiest bits. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

That comment is one of those comments CVS created by replacing the `$Id$` string present in files.
In that comment you read the CVS username of the person who committed the last change to that file, [killes@www.drop.org](https://www.drupal.org/u/killeswwwdroporg), who was a Drupal 4.7 core maintainer, and who helped to push out the release during Dries' absence between March and April 2006.

To answer your question, that site is running on Drupal 4.7. It could be Drupal [4.7.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.5), [4.7.6](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.6), [4.7.7](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.7), [4.7.8](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.8), [4.7.9](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.9), [4.7.10](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.10), or [4.7.11](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.11), for which the first lines of the *index.php* file are the following ones.

```php
// $Id: index.php,v 1.90.2.1 2006/12/12 13:50:59 killes Exp $

/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
 * prints the appropriate page.
 */

require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();
```

If you look at the same lines for that same file in [Drupal 4.7.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.4), you will see they are the following ones.

```php
<?php
// $Id: index.php,v 1.90 2006/01/27 18:51:51 dries Exp $

/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
 * prints the appropriate page.
 */

require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();
```

If you look at the content of the other files, you could be able to understand exactly which Drupal 4.7 version is, but that would not help you much, as migrating a Drupal 4.7 site would be problematic independently from the exact Drupal 4.7 version the site is using.